# Selecting outer keys by values in inner keys dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary which looks like:

```
mydict = {'user1':{source:'a',source_id:'1'}, 'user2':{source:'a',source_id:'1'}, 'user3':{source:'b',source_id:'1'}, ...}
```

I would like to collect all upper keys grouped by distinct source/source_id
Such as:

for source 'a' and 'source_id' 1

```
['user1', 'user2']
```

for source 'b' and 'source_id' 1

```
['user3']
```

and so on

Distinct number of source/source_id will differ most of the time

Comment: Your `mylist` is not a valid list

Comment: sorry it was a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension to do this

```
{key:value for key, value in d.items() if value.get('source') == 'a' and value.get('source_id') == '1'}
```

More generally

```
def filterBy(source, source_id):
    return {key:value for key, value in d.items() if value.get('source') == source and value.get('source_id') == source_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with an if condition:

```
>>> mylist = {'user1':{'source':'a','source_id':'1'}, 'user2':{'source':'a','source_id':'1'}, 'user3':{'source':'b','source_id':'1'}}
>>> [i for i in mylist if (mylist[i]['source']=='a' and mylist[i]['source_id']=='1')]
['user2', 'user1']
>>> [i for i in mylist if (mylist[i]['source']=='b' and mylist[i]['source_id']=='1')]
['user3']
```

Comment: @user3613909 I didn't know that, but I had to for the example. Should work the same if you don't.